# Animating an element being added on click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a contact icon which, when pressed moves to the side, revealing the contact information. I would like the text to remain centred and for the contact info to fade in. So far I have this:

```
<div class="contacts">
    <div class="contactIcon">ICON<span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span></div>
    <div class="contactIcon">ICON<span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span></div>
</div>
```

```
 let contactIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.contactIcon');
    for (let i = 0; i < contactIcon.length; i++) {
        contactIcon[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            let contactInfo = contactIcon[i].querySelector('.contactInfo');
            if (contactInfo.style.display == 'none') {
                contactInfo.style.visibility = 'visible'
                contactInfo.style.display = 'inline';
                contactInfo.style.maxWidth ='100px';
            }
            else {
                contactInfo.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                contactInfo.style.display = 'none';
                contactInfo.style.maxWidth = '0';
            }
        });
```

```
.contactIcon {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.contactInfo {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    max-width: 500px;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s, max-width 0.6s linear;
}
```

The code works to a degree, the icon shifts to allow space, but there is no animation and I'm not sure why, I've tried toggling a '.hide' class, but also couldn't get that to work. Also it takes 2 clicks to make the content appear, and I'm struggling to understand that also.

Answer (score 1):

The latter consern is easy to answer: `contactInfo.style.display == 'none'` only detects inline styles, so you must remove `display:none;` from css and attach it to html `span`. as for animations, `display: none` spoils everything here, choose `opacity` or `width` to make element visually disappear.

```html
  <div class="contactIcon">ICON
    <span class="contactInfo" style="opacity: 0"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span>
  </div>
```

```css
.contactInfo {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 500px;
  /*transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s, max-width 0.6s linear;*/
  transition: all 1.6s;
}
```

```js
let contactIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".contactIcon");

for (let i = 0; i < contactIcon.length; i++) {
  contactIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let contactInfo = contactIcon[i].querySelector(".contactInfo");
    if (contactInfo.style.opacity == "0") {
      contactInfo.style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
      contactInfo.style.opacity = "0";
    }
  });
}
```

p.s. I attached inline style to make you see, how it has been detected with `contactInfo.style.opacity == "0"` here is better way without inline style:

```js
let contactIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".contactIcon");

for (let i = 0; i < contactIcon.length; i++) {
  contactIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let contactInfo = contactIcon[i].querySelector(".contactInfo");
    if (contactInfo.style.opacity == "1") {
      contactInfo.style.opacity = "0";
      contactInfo.style.width = "0";
    } else {
      contactInfo.style.opacity = "1";
      contactInfo.style.width = "92px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.contactIcon {
  width: 240px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactInfo {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1.6s;
  /*transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s, max-width 0.6s linear;*/
}
```

```html
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contactIcon">ICON<span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span></div>
      <div class="contactIcon">
        ICON
        <span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm struggling with is that I'd like the icons to stack one above the other before the contactInfo is revealed, which is why I've been playing with the display property, as I would like the contactInfo to be out of the flow of the document while not showing.

Comment: after click you want to move the other icon behind clicked one and so vesually disappear? did I get it?

Comment: Not quite, what I would like is for the icon to appear centered in the container, and once clicked it should look like this: 'ICON (+xx) xxxxxxxx', still centered in the container

Comment: I have updated the code, check it!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let contactIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.contactIcon');
    for (let i = 0; i < contactIcon.length; i++) {
        contactIcon[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            let contactInfo = contactIcon[i].querySelector('.contactInfo');
            let icon = contactIcon[i].querySelector('.icon');
            if (contactInfo.style.opacity == 0) {
                icon.style.marginLeft = '-40px';
                icon.style.opacity = 0;
                contactInfo.style.display = 'inline';
                contactInfo.style.opacity = 1;
                contactInfo.style.maxWidth ='100px';
            }
            else {
                icon.style.marginLeft = '0';
                icon.style.opacity = 1;
                contactInfo.style.opacity = 0;
                contactInfo.style.maxWidth = '0';
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.contactIcon {
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor : pointer;
}

.icon {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
 }

.contactInfo {
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 500px;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
    <div class="contactIcon"><i class="icon 1">✈️</i><span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span></div>
    <div class="contactIcon"><i class="icon 2">✈️</i><span class="contactInfo"> (+xx)xxxxxxx</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm struggling with is that I'd like the icons to stack one above the other before the contactInfo is revealed, which is why I've been playing with the display property, as I would like the contactInfo to be out of the flow of the document while not showing, and ideally the icon wouldn't disappear, simply move to the left to make way for the contactInfo.